# Do I need to purchase Minecraft again for my second iOS device?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm considering getting an iPhone soon. Will I only have to buy Minecraft once or will I have to buy it again if I buy a new iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

## No

The app store has a family feature where as long as your devices are in the same family and/or paired, you can download the game for free.

You should also be able to restore any purchases you have made, although I am unsure about that last part.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR: No, you don't need to buy it again.

All purchases on the Apple App Store are associated with your Apple ID or iTunes account. If you get a new iPhone (or even an iPad or any other iOS device), as long as you sign in to the App Store with the same Apple ID as you used to buy Minecraft, you won't need to pay for it again. You can just search for it and download it. You'll notice that, because you've already purchased the app, it will no longer display the price as the download button.